# Visual Studio + Xamarin Forms: Tanto tarda en levantar el emulador?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Hice una app bien simple con un etiqueta y entry. Compilo, doy F5 y me tarda una eternidad en levantar el emulador con la app corriendo.

*¿Ésto es normal?*
Mas allá de eso les cuento que no pude hacer que entre la lista de emuladores aparezca mi celular (previamente conectado vía usb).

*¿Me falta configurar algo?*
Aclaro que tengo el SDK bien instalado y con todas las rutas correctas (con el tilde verde).

Comment: depende de tu computadora. Te recomiendo que levantes el emulador primero y luego compiles la app.'

Comment: Si levanto el emulador primero, cuando presiono f5 desde vs me levanta otro emulador.

Comment: es que estás seleccionando otro emulador, mira bien cuál vas a debuggear y cuál has levantado :D

Comment: Si no tienes una buena maquina, el emulador se demora una eternidad; lo mejor es que coloques tu celular en modo desarrollador habilitando la opción depuración usb.

Comment: ¿Cuáles son las características de tu equipo de desarrollo? Un buen emulador es Genymotion, te recomiendo probarlo. Al respecto del celular, instala los drivers en tu equipo para que lo reconozca Visual Studio. También puedes intentar conectarlo usando otro puerto usb para que se "reinstale"

Comment: Es un Core I5 con 12G de ram.

Comment: Genymotion? Lo voy a buscar.. Gracias!